# How to get index of elements in a nested list kdb

Tags: kdb

Lets say I have a nested `` list: (`a`b`c;`d`e`f;`g`h`i) ``
I have another list of indexes `i:(1 0 3)`

How do I use the list of indexes, to retrieve symbols from the list. The desired output should be `` (`b`d`) `` (the last symbol is null)

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW the second pair of parens is redundant: `i:1 0 3` suffices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to use the apply operator `@` with the each-both iterator `'`:

```
q)list @' i
`b`d`
```

Comment: More precisely, [Index At](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/#index-at) [Each](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each)